# OpenCV resize error(-215:Assertion Failed)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, resize

**This is my code for building a linear classifier for images and cv2.resize() is throwing error while converting the image from original size to (32,32)**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

labels = ["dog","cat","panda"]
np.random.seed(1)

W = np.random.randn(3,3072)
b = np.random.randn(3)

orig = cv2.imread("panda_00001.png")
image = cv2.resize(orig,(32,32)).flatten()

scores = W.dot(image) + b

for (label,score) in zip(labels,scores):
    print("[INFO] {}:{:.2f}".format(label,score))

cv2.putText(orig,"Label:{}".format(labels[np.argmax(scores)]),(10,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.9,(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow("Image",orig)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

**Getting this error on execution**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linearclassifier.py", line 11, in <module>
    image = cv2.resize(orig,(32,32)).flatten()
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Comment: After `orig` type `cv2.imshow('out', orig)` will the image displayed?

Comment: Your image is empty. Either it is corrupt or does not exist in your working directory. You likely need to provide a path to panda_00001.png

Comment: @fmw42 thanks. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture path seems to be wrong or invalid.

It's always good practice to integrate a null check to the read picture in your script:

eg:

```
import cv2
... 
img = cv2.imread("myImage.jpg")

if (img.size == 0):
   # error handling or throw exception here!

# do stuff with image here
```

Comment: my image size is not zero but i got the error